# aws cli run instances with name tag and EBS volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to launch new EC2 instances into AWS on the command line using the cli. What I need to do is apply a name tag and add EBS volumes. The EBS volumes should also have name tags. This is what I have so far.

And I'm getting a usage error:

```
λ aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxx --count 1 --instance-type r3.xlarge --key-name timd --security-group-ids sg-xxxxx --subnet-id subnet-xxxxx --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=ENC_TEST}]' 'ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=Engagement,Value=8000xxxx}]' --block-device-mappings 'DeviceName=/dev/sdf,VirtualName=data,Ebs={Encrypted=yes,DeleteOnTermination=yes,VolumeSize=250,VolumeType=string}' --profile=govcloud-nonprod
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: --tag-specifications, 'ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=Engagement,Value=800000xxxx}]', 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=ENC_TEST}]'
```

Can someone help me past this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--tag-specifications` was an feature introduced back end of [March 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/new-tag-ec2-instances-ebs-volumes-on-creation/)

Make sure to update your aws CLI version to reflect this change.

Also the `--block-device-mapping` is incorrect, the definition is

```
        {
          "DeviceName": "string",
          "VirtualName": "string",
          "Ebs": {
            "Encrypted": true|false,
            "DeleteOnTermination": true|false,
            "Iops": integer,
            "SnapshotId": "string",
            "VolumeSize": integer,
            "VolumeType": "standard"|"io1"|"gp2"|"sc1"|"st1"
          },
          "NoDevice": "string"
        }
        ...
```

so you should have

```
--block-device-mappings "[{\"DeviceName\":\"/dev/sdf\",\"VirtualName\":\"data\",\"Ebs\":{\"Encrypted\"=true,\"DeleteOnTermination\"=true,\"VolumeSize\"=250,/"VolumeType\"=\"standard\"}}]"
```